# I get Makefile:1119: recipe for target 'sln_build' failed while installing monodevelop

Tags: c#, linux, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I get this error while trying to install monodevelop on slackware. All its dependencies are already installed.

```
Errors:

/tmp/SBo/monodevelop-6.3.0.864/main/Main.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/tmp/SBo/monodevelop-6.3.0.864/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.dotnet.v14.1.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/BuildEngine.v4.0.cs(53,12): error CS1061: Type `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection' does not contain a definition for `SetGlobalProperty' and no extension method `SetGlobalProperty' of type `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

     102 Warning(s)
     1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:03:06.0246790
Makefile:1119: recipe for target 'sln_build' failed
make[1]: *** [sln_build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/SBo/monodevelop-6.3.0.864/main'
Makefile:675: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I've already tried another referenceassemblies-pcl sources but the error still persists

Comment: Your Slackware version is missing in your question. .... Official Slackware Forum : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/

Comment: My bad. I'm using Slackware 14.2

Comment: Well, then please ask at https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ ... to get a fix / an updated patch for https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/development/monodevelop/?search=monodevelop

Comment: I get it. This means "go ask elsewhere".